# Elemets don't float when web browser page is zoomed out (Crtl -)

Tags: css, css-float, border, element, zooming

Try to resize window to the minimum (CTRL-):
http://jsfiddle.net/Zty9k/13/

Html

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PBuDAFH.gif"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PBuDAFH.gif"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PBuDAFH.gif"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i.imgur.com/PBuDAFH.gif"></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
 width:304px;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
ul li{
 float:left;
 list-style: none;
 margin:0;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 height:150px;
}
```

Elements will collapse.

The strange thing, when removing the border and adjustig the with to 300px then elements won't collapse when screen resized.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by collapsing? They don't fit next to each other anymore in my case. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

As your image size is 150x150px. You should use `width: 308px;`  that your lists are four times and applying the border you calculated just 4 but you should calculate both side of border so it become 2*4 = 8px .

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zty9k/14/)

Alternatively you could use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

To explain why your code fails I will try to explain firstly how web browsers zoom works:

When you execute zoom action in a browser the browser multiplies or divides(depending on if you zoom in or zoom out) all the measures of the [DOM elements](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)(`ul`, `li`, `img`...).

So after zoom out your page this is how your browser interprets sizes:

```
/*
zoom out 1:2
2px(original) = 1px(zoomed out) 
*/
ul{
 width:152px; /* 304/2 */
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}
ul li{
 float:left;
 list-style: none;
 margin:0;
 border: 1px solid #000; 
 height:75px; /* 150/2 */
}
```

And what happens with the border? `1px` is a size, no? Yes, it is but `1px` can't be divided because screens are composed by pixels, and obviously you can't render `0.5px` so border size remains `1px` after zoom out and this makes the `li` can't be floated.

#### So what is the solution?

You can set `ul` width to `308px` as @C-link says but this is a bad practice [try this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zty9k/17/). Use only `box-sizing` property doesn't works but instead you can combine it with percentage values:

```
ul{
  width:304px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
ul li{
  float:left;
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto; /* set its size to the size of its content */
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;    
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;    
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block; /* To remove the bottom space, comment it to see what happens */
}
```

#### And here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zty9k/18/)